# Get selected picker view component string value

Tags: ios, objective-c, text, label, uipickerview

I have a picker view and it has four components. I have created a label that is displayed. I have a two array populating the first component (component 0) label text, and the last component (component 3) label text. For the center two components, I have the label text set like this

`label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row];`.

NOTE: this is in the `viewForRow:` method. I have a button below it that I want to get selected data from each component. How can I get the string value of the selected center two components?

I know how to get the two with arrays but I'm unsure how to get the selected label text. Forgive me if there's some very simple answer I have just missed or overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the delegate method, pickerView:didSelectRow:inComponent:, which will give you the row and component that was selected. You can use that information to access the correct index in the appropriate array.

Comment: The thing is I don't have arrays for the center two components. I have an array for the first and last but not the middle ones. I was just wondering if I could somehow get that string value of the label text.

Comment: @MiloGosnell, since you're just putting the row value in those components, you know what that should be from the row that's passed in to the delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

UIPickerView has a "`selectedRowInComponent:`" method which can help you.  You can get some reference from this [link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html) too-

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView didSelectRow: (NSInteger)row inComponent: (NSInteger) component {
    rowValue = row;
}
```

just keep the row index in global attribute then get the value like this

```
NSStrin *string=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rowValue];
```

Comment: Thanks I just realized that I was being dumb and and totally missed that I was labeling the text with the row. My bad. Thanks anyway. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

On selecting the button just get the current picker selected row

```
NSInteger row = [yourPicker selectedRowInComponent:0];
//Choose it for other components
NSString *yourComponentValue  = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Or

```
 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   NSString *yourComponentValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[yourarray objectAtIndex:row];
   //Imagine this method will be called whenever the user scrolls. Usability point-of-view i would suggest not to update any of your UI here
}
```

This UPicker delegate method will be called when the user scrolls the picker and the scrolling is finished.

Choose where and when you want it to be